# Is flask-assets putting minified files in right directory?

Tags: python, flask, webassets, flask-assets

I'm working to modify a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask) Flask app. I'm working locally on WIN7 .

I've set up bower to install the front end dependencies under the static root by using a .bowerrc file in the document root containing:

```
{ "directory" : "myflaskapp/static/bower_components" }
```

This cookiecutter uses flask-assets to manage the project assets. Following https://adambard.com/blog/fresh-flask-setup/  I've modified myflaskapp/assets.py file :

```
from flask_assets import Bundle, Environment
import os

css = Bundle(
    "libs/bootstrap/dist/css/spacelab/bootstrap.css",
    "bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
    "css/style.css",
    "css/home.css",
    filters="cssmin",
    output="public/css/common.css"
)

js = Bundle(
    "libs/jQuery/dist/jquery.js",
    "libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js",
    "bower_components/moment/moment.js",
    "bower_components/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
    "js/plugins.js",
    filters='jsmin',
    output="public/js/common.js"
)


assets = Environment()

assets.register("js_all", js)
assets.register("css_all", css)
```

The debug setting is set to false, meaning the assets should be compressed and minified.

Before I send a request:

[image]

After:

[image]

shouldn't the files go in static/public/css and static/public/js

Comment: Are you sure that the minified files are stored in the static folder? Maybe they are stored in memory or in a different directory. Did you try already to request the files as a client? Maybe they are delivered minified.

Answer (score 1):

This particular `cookiecutter` recipe has a `public` `Blueprint` that declares that its static files go into the `static` directory. I'm not sure why the author included empty `static/public/{css,js}` directories; they are probably just leftovers from an earlier stage of development and were neglected. I've removed the `static/public` directory in my instantiation of this recipe (well, a similar one with a similar problem) to no harm.